# How to intercept flutter back-button when keyboard is shown

Tags: flutter, keyboard, back-button

I want to intercept the back-button of the soft keyboard in flutter. So when I want to close the keyboard by pressing the back-button I want an additional function to be called.
How can I do that?

**Keyboard Back button**

[image]

Comment: try `WillPopScope` widget

Comment: @haroldolivieri `WillPopScope` will not detect the back button of the keyboard.  I have already tried it and it does not work. I have added an answer below, you can check it out.

Comment: as far as I know Android OS doesn't expose the keyboard down button in a listener. @KarimElghamry's answer is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the [keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility#-readme-tab-) package to achieve this.

**Working Example**

the following code displays a `SnackBar` once the keyboard is dismissed.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
      onHide: () {
        _key.currentState.showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text("Keyboard closed"),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _key,
        body: Center(
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to save `id` of the listener and remove it in `dispose()` method like so: `KeyboardVisibilityNotification().removeListener(id);`

Comment: this package has nullsafety and android v2 issues

Answer (score 0):

you can use the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility package to achieve this.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility_example/keyboard_dismiss_demo.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility_example/provider_demo.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Demo(),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardDismissOnTap(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Keyboard Visibility Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProviderDemo()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text('Provider Demo'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => KeyboardDismissDemo()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text('KeyboardDismiss Demo'),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Input box for keyboard test',
                  ),
                ),
                Container(height: 60.0),
                KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(builder: (context, visible) {
                  return Text(
                    'The keyboard is: ${visible ? 'VISIBLE' : 'NOT VISIBLE'}',
                  );
                }),
                Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```