# Flutter: Use the keyboard to move the text

Tags: flutter, text, keyboard, cursor, move

I intend to create a simple keyboard with the bare essentials. How is it possible to use the keyboard (keys) to move the cursor in a multi-line text (to the left, top right and bottom)? How can I delete right?

Comment: I am not sure what are u referring to. Do u want to create ur own onscreen keyboard and intercept keys? Can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727350/how-to-intercept-flutter-back-button-when-keyboard-is-shown

Comment: yes, I would like to design an onscreen keyboard with which I can navigate in the text.

Comment: Ok, did that link help?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it won't help me.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to navigate in a text field with press buttons (not with keyboard)?

Comment: Did you look into the Gesture detector?